# Python While loop (check line 6)

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, do-while

```
def purchace():
    total=0
    while keepgoing == ("y" or "Y"):

    item= float(input("Enter price of the item")
    if (item<=100):
        dis=(.15*item)
        price=(item-dis)
    else:
        dis=(.25*item)
        price=(item-dis)
    total+= item
    keepgoing = raw_input("Do you want to add more items? (y/n)")

print("Your total is ",total)                    
print("Thank you")

def main():
    purchase()
main()
```

There is a syntax error on line 6 " if (item<=100):" it highlights specifically on the colon ":", isn't that how one makes if statement in python? And should I have keeping going defined before the while loop?

Comment: Your `while` condition is wrong as well. `while keepgoing in ("y", "Y"):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing right-parenthesis on the previous line:

```
item = float(input("Enter price of the item"))
```

Comment: Also, note that you're using a *lot* of unncessary parentheses in this code.  You don't need them for simple assignments and if expressions.

Comment: Wow really?? I checked that at least 3 times... Thanks!!

Comment: Noted. However, thats the way the professor taught us

Comment: You'll need to initialize keepgoing *before* the loop.  At the bottom of the loop, I think you want to add "price" to total, not "item".

Comment: If you're going into professional programming later, you'll need to un-learn some of the things you're doing here.  Check out the "PEP-8" standards for typical Python coding style.

Comment: Oh ... whenever you get to a point of resolution, don't forget to "accept" your favourite answer (I anticipate more coming along).  This properly retires the question for the StackOverflow archives.

Comment: Good.  Also, check with your professor to see whether that programming style is required for the class.  If not, I recommend that you switch to PEP-8 as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
def purchase():
total=0
keepgoing = "y"
while keepgoing == ("y" or "Y"):

    item= float(input("Enter price of the item: "))
    if (item<=100):
        dis=(.15*item)
        price=(item-dis)
    else:
        dis=(.25*item)
        price=(item-dis)
    total+= price
    keepgoing = raw_input("Do you want to add more items? (y/n)")

print("Your total is ",total)                    
print("Thank you")

def main():
    purchase()
main()
```

This one runs perfectly, on the orginal i missed up a couple other things too